# Does performFetchWithCompletionHandler will be called after the device was rebooted or the app killed?

Tags: ios, background-fetch

Does `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` (fetch background mode) will be called after the device was rebooted or the app killed ?

I mean does the system will start the app in background and fire `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` if the app is not actually running ?

Comment: try to in simulator Debug > Simulate Background Fetch and check.

Comment: i want to know on real device :( simulator often behave not like real device, especially regarding location